# Why Is "NOT NULL" not a constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I want to add a PRIMARY KEY to an existing column table :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT column_name_PK PRIMARY KEY (column_name);
```

Now, If I want to add a NOT NULL to an existing column table :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER column column_name INTEGER(or other data type) NOT NULL;
```

Isn't `NOT NULL` a constraint ? 
Why for a PRIMARY KEY is `ADD CONSTRAINT`

and for a `NOT NULL` is not `ADD CONSTRAINT` but `ALTER COLUMN` ?
To my eyes, `NOT NULL` is also a kind of constraint..

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34096328/880990) to the SO question [How to find the name of not-null constraints in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096290/how-to-find-the-name-of-not-null-constraints-in-sql-server)

Comment: NOT NULL is a constraint in the same sense that NVARCHAR(50) is a constraint.

Comment: You can also specify that a column is a `PRIMARY KEY` in the table `CREATE` statement. `CREATE TABLE MyTable (ID int PRIMARY KEY);` is valid syntax (although I don't recommend it as the OK would have a automatically generated name).

Answer (score 3):

Specifying `NOT NULL` means 'the column must have a value'. It only means that some value **must be present**, but it says nothing about *what those values should be*. Note that in SQL terms, `NULL` itself is not a value but it is *the absence of a value*.

A `CONSTRAINT` on the other hand is a rule for the allowed values. You can even have a constraint on NULL columns, and then such a `CONSTRAINT` for the allowed values is enforced only if a non-NULL value is present.

Comment: Another way of thinking about it, in more functional programming terms, is that nullability is part of the type of the column, and constraints are value restrictions beyond what the type system can handle, similar to design-by-contract.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: If the answer helped you, you could upvote and/or Accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `NOT NULL` inline when you declare the parameter. Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE People
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    Name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Notes NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as the `NULL` or `NOT NULL` actually being part of the type declaration.  A field that can hold an `Integer` and also can hold a `NULL` is a different type than one that can hold an `Integer` but never a `NULL`.

Consider

```
create type IntegerIsSometimesNull from integer null

create type IntegerIsNeverNull  from integer not null

go

create table DifferentType ( N IntegerIsSometimesNull,
                             I IntegerIsNeverNull      )
```

Here we see that `NULL` and `NOT NULL` are actually a part of the type declaration.

Consider also that these fields require a different amount of space in the database.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 0):

> To my eyes, NOT NULL is also a kind of constraint..

Yes.  Data Types, NULL-ness, CHECK CONSTRAINTS, and FOREIGN KEY constraints are all concerned with defining the "domain" of the column.  A "domain" is the set of possible values for a column, and is a fundamental concept of the relational model.

In most RDBMS systems domains are implemented by a combination of data types and constraints.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer!